# SQL Design Hirearchy?

Tags: sql

EDIT :

i think the bottom point here is that im asking what the best way is to store LIST data ...

for example if i had 20 sites under 1 client

would i

1. put the sites into the client table seperated by a comma 
   ( then break them a part in the software )
2. make a sites table with the client info in it to reference the sites? - ( therefore makeing the client table unnessasary? )

then if i had 20 different comments per site would i

1. take the client table that has my sites seperated by commas and add my comment sites|comment,site|comment,|site,|comment, and so on ?
2. create another table and throw all information in there in one row referencing the sites

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the key to table1? i.e. what column or combination of columns uniquely identifies a record in table1?

Comment: You ask how to relate data in two tables after stating the the two tables are in no way related?

If you are attempting to relate records from one table to another, use foreign key constraints, if you are asking how to surface that data in a single query, join across the tables. How the DAL issues the query (e.g. using a `DataReader`) doesn't seem relevant to your question here.

Comment: Just my opinion, but this is a pretty basic database design question - unless I'm totally missing your question.  You should probably read up on the topic before heading down the wrong road, which can cause you major grief.

Comment: Please use some kind of real-world example for your table and column names. This `1Column`, `11Column`, `111Column` stuff makes it much more difficult to conceptually grasp.

Comment: edited, thanks for the replies so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What columns make each table unique?

You would typically create a surrogate key using an autonumber column if you don't have an obvious key in your data.  You would then use this one column to establish relationships between tables.

Comment: Thanks took me some research to grasp what and how a relationship works but this definatly seems to be the way to go instead of trying to do what i did ( total failure in the future ) , thanks again for all your comments and this answer.